# supervisor で複数のサービス起動前にコマンドを実行したい

Tags: linux, supervisor

supervisor を使って python のプログラムをデーモン化して複数起動したのですが
各デーモン起動時に conda env をなければ作成あれば流用というコードになっていて
時々中途半端な状態で venv が作成されてしまうことがあって起動に失敗するため
起動前に venv を削除したいです

ただ作成する venv 名はサービスの内部で計算されるためコマンド時点ではわからず
サービスごとに自分の前回作った venv を削除するということが難しいため
特定のプレフィックスのついた venv を全削除したいと思ってるのですが

rm /venvpath/prefix-* を各サービスで読んでしまうと
タイミングによって先に起動してすでに venv を新しく作成中の物まで消してしまうかもしれません

supervisor には起動順を指定できる priority というパラメータがあるみたいで
priority を各サービスより小さくした rm コマンドを読んだ場合
先に削除が完了されることって保証されるんでしょうか？

なんとなく supervisor がやってることって子プロセスを作って親が exit するだけで
親が exit した時点で子プロセスで実行される rm コマンド実行タイミングは保証されない感じがするんですが、親プロセス自体でコマンドを実行する（非デーモンプロセスの起動）みたいなことってできないでしょうか？

また supervisor や priority に限らず
このような要件で他にうまい方法があったら教えていただきたいです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

後に起動したいプロセスを全部自動起動を false にして
べつに自動起動 true にしたサービスから

削除　→　ほかのプロセスを順番に起動

というスクリプトを実行するのはどうでしょうか

```
#!/bin/bash

rm /venvpath/prefix-* 
sudo supervisorctl start program1
sudo supervisorctl start program2
sudo supervisorctl start program3
  :
sudo supervisorctl remove 自分自身
```

を実行するサービスだけを自動起動するようにしておけば
ほかのプロセス起動前に必ず rm 実行できるんじゃないかと思います

Comment: うまく行きました。自動起動をオフにできたのですね。

Comment: と思ったんですが最後の sudo supervisorctl remove 自分自身だけ runnning 中だとエラーになるようです。それでも３回リトライされて最後は起動するんですが、手動で再起動した時に毎回実行されないようにと言うことかと思いますが、この行をなくしたらうまくいったようです